# Problema al importar datos de excel a SQL Server con SQL Import and Export Wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, importación

El problema que me surge es el siguiente. Estoy tratando de importar datos de un archivo de Excel a SQL Server utilizando el asistente para hacerlo, pero durante el paso final de copiado de los registro marca el error que dejo en la captura. Muy agradecido si alguien pudiera darme una mano[image: Este es el mensaje que arroja el sistema]

Comment: El primer error te dice que no tienes espacio en la base de datos para el fileGroup `Primary`. Por tanto no tienes espacio  en la base de datos para insertar lo que estás importando. [Insuficiente espacio en filegroup primary](https://www.sqlshack.com/resolving-sql-server-errors-the-primary-filegroup-is-full/)

Comment: Si, intente añadir mas memoria a la primary, pero ahora me envía el erro "the transaction log for database is full due to 'nothing'"

Comment: Haz un backup del transaction log file. Y luego haz un shrink del mismo. Así se vaciará. [Sql backup transaction log and shrink](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-transaction-log-backup-truncate-and-shrink-operations/)